# FPDF Doesn't output accents or simbols

Tags: php, zend-framework, fpdf, fpdi

i got a huge text in spanish, when i add it to the pdf with `Write(5,$text)` it outputs well but it doesn't show any accents(é,á,ó) or simbols like $ or &.
i've tried using the output in UTF-8
`$pdf->Output("I","Contrato",true);` 
but still doesn't show the text like it should.
Any other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to decode your utf-8, like so:

```
Write(5, utf8_decode($text));
```

An alternative is using `iconv()`, like so:

```
 Write(5, iconv('UTF-8', 'iso-8859-1', $text));
```

Comment: It worked! thank you so much. I thought that with the output it should be enough but i guess it wasn't.

Comment: OMG @schellingerht where have you been! 6 years this comment has been sitting here waiting for me to find it! I've struggled so much with this... utf8_decode() fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The code below helped after I spent many hours searching for a hint...

```
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US');
  $val = iconv('UTF-8', 'iso-8859-1', $variable_containing_special_chars);
  $pdf->Cell(x_axis,y_axis,$val);
```